# Java PatternSyntaxException when first character of regex is *

Tags: java, regex

So I have this snippet of Java code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("* bar");
Matcher m = p.matcher("foo bar");
System.out.println(m.find());
```

However when I run it I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
>   * bar
>   ^

Not sure why this happens as when I replace `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("* bar")` with `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("foo *")`
everything works as expected and the console outputs true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` in regexes has a [special meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of *repeat zero or more times* (aka *empty string*, `x`, `xx` and so on will all be matched by `x*` for example).

When it is in the beginning, the regex engine has no idea what to repeat, hence the error. In the second example, you were saying *`foo`, followed by zero or more spaces*.

If you want to match a literal `*`, you have to escape it - `\\*`.

Comment: @bowTI, you can use `bar$`. `$` is an anchor for end of line.

Comment: @bowTI, additionally, if you want to make the entire string matched by it, you can use `.*bar$`.

Comment: You can reference the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy) too.

Answer (score 1):

`*` in regex means zero or more repetition of the preceding symbol. Since you don't specify any preceding symbol, you get an error. You could use `.` to mean any character. Hence, for your usecase, you could write your regex as `.* bar`.